# Dispaly hex color as background color of textbox after conversion from rbg value to hex code using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="text"  name="red"  id="txtRed"/>
<input type="text" name="green" id="txtGreen" />
<input type="text" name="blue"  id="txtBlue"/>
<input type="text"  id="displaycolor" style="height:50px;width:50px" />
```

This is my view, I have 4 textbox(red,blue,green and display color) at time of entering rgb for  textbox ,and same time i want to convert the rgb to hex color code ,show that hex color in 4th textbox.                       `

```
function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    var r = $("#txtRed").val();
    var g = $("#txtGreen").val();
    var b = $("#txtBlue").val();
    return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}

$("#txtRed").keypress(function () {         
    rgbToHex();
})
$("#txtGreen").keypress(function () {
    rgbToHex();
})
$("#txtBlue").keypress(function () {
    rgbToHex();
})

var componentToHex = function (rgb) {
    debugger
    var hex = Number(rgb).toString(16);
    return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}
```

this is my javascript code, conversion working, I don't how to display that hex color in that 4th 
textbox, please help me

Comment: `$("#displaycolor").val(rgbToHex())`  https://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add an additional step that actually sets the content and colour of the `displaycolor` input to the value you generated.

Something like this would do it:

```
function setDisplayColor() {
  var color = rgbToHex();
  $('#displaycolor').val(color);
  $('#displaycolor').css('background-color', color);
}
```

You should also use the `keyup` event instead of `keypress`, and in these call `setDisplayColor()`:

```
$("#txtRed").keyup(function () {
  setDisplayColor();
});
```

The following snippet shows this in action:

```js
function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
  var r = $("#txtRed").val();
  var g = $("#txtGreen").val();
  var b = $("#txtBlue").val();
  return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}

function setDisplayColor() {
  var color = rgbToHex();
  $('#displaycolor').val(color);
  $('#displaycolor').css('background-color', color);
}

$("#txtRed").keyup(function () {
  setDisplayColor();
});
$("#txtGreen").keyup(function () {
  setDisplayColor();
});
$("#txtBlue").keyup(function () {
  setDisplayColor();
});

var componentToHex = function (rgb) {
  var hex = Number(rgb).toString(16);
  return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="red" id="txtRed"/>
<input type="text" name="green" id="txtGreen" />
<input type="text" name="blue" id="txtBlue"/>
<input type="text" id="displaycolor" style="height:50px;width:100px" />
```

Comment: I don't want a show that hex code, I want to display the only color.

Answer (score 1):

in function rgbToHex, You can use:

```
function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
         var r = $("#txtRed").val();
         var g = $("#txtGreen").val();
         var b = $("#txtBlue").val();
         var hex = "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b)
         $("#displaycolor").css('backgroud-color',hex)
}
```

Comment: sry not working this method, showing hex code(eg:#808000) in that 4th textbox, I want to display color instead of hex code

Answer (score 1):

You just get element and set value like this:

```
$("#displaycolor").css('background-color',color)
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this work as you require you simply need to set the `hex` result as the `val()` of the `#displaycolor` field.

However you should note that you can both DRY this code up and improve it in several ways. For example by assigning common classes to invoke a single event handler for all elements, providing the `rgb` values as arguments to the `rgbToHex()` function, separating calculation and data retrieval logic in the functions (ie. the Single Responsibility Principle) and also by enforcing the limits of the value entered to be 0-255. Try this:

```js
function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
  return "#" + componentToHex(r || 0) + componentToHex(g || 0) + componentToHex(b || 0);
}

var componentToHex = function(value) {
  return ('00' + parseInt(value, 10).toString(16)).slice(-2);
}

$(".rgb-update").on('input', function() {
  var r = Math.min(parseInt($('#txtRed').val(), 10) || 0, 255);
  var g = Math.min(parseInt($('#txtGreen').val(), 10) || 0, 255);
  var b = Math.min(parseInt($('#txtBlue').val(), 10) || 0, 255);
  var hex = rgbToHex(r, g, b);
  $('#displaycolor').val(hex).css('background-color', hex);
}).trigger('input');
```

```css
#displaycolor {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="red" id="txtRed" class="rgb-update" maxlength="3" size="3" value="255" />
<input type="text" name="green" id="txtGreen" class="rgb-update" maxlength="3" size="3" value="255" />
<input type="text" name="blue" id="txtBlue" class="rgb-update" maxlength="3" size="3" value="255" />

<p>
  <input type="text" name="hex" id="displaycolor" readonly="true" />
</p>
```

I'd suggest using `range` inputs to help even more with the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `keyup` instead of `keypress`

```js
$("#txtRed, #txtGreen, #txtBlue").on('keyup', function () {         
    var r = $("#txtRed").val();
    var g = $("#txtGreen").val();
    var b = $("#txtBlue").val();
    var color = "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
    $("#displaycolor").val(color).css({'background-color':color});
});

function componentToHex (rgb) {
    var hex = Number(rgb).toString(16);
    return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"  name="red"  id="txtRed"/>
<input type="text" name="green" id="txtGreen" />
<input type="text" name="blue"  id="txtBlue"/>
<input type="text"  id="displaycolor" style="height:50px;width:50px" />
```